# Compare string in format HH:MM to time now in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a string of the format "HH:MM" and need to compare it to the time now in Python.

I did read through the datetime documentation but could not figure out an elegant to perform my comparison (being a total rookie does not help either:))

Thanks for reading this!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [`datetimes`'s `strptime()`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#datetime.datetime.strptime) function to convert the string to a valid `datetime`:

```
>>>d=datetime.datetime.strptime('15:30','%H:%M')
```

and later compare it to `now`'s `time()`:

```
>>>dnow=datetime.datetime.now()  #11:42 am here ;)
>>>dnow.time() < d.time()
True
```

You can read also doc's [strftime() and strptime() Behavior](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html?highlight=datetime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) which explained these methods and have a very good table resuming the *directives* to parse dates.

Comment: Also be aware that you need to be sure that the time you're given is in the right time zone, and that the wrap-around behaviour around midnight will sometimes be surprising.

Comment: @SteveJessop Thanks for the comments, I just provide a very simple answer given the contents of the question (which are not very deep). If this turns to be wrong or not what the OP was looking for I'll delete the answer or modify it, but so far haven't got any feedback from the OP :)

Comment: Indeed, if the questioner sees my comment and makes the question deeper as a result then I consider that a win :-)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you all for spending time helping me!