# Filtering Pandas DataFrame on Time values

Tags: python, pandas, time

I have a Pandas DataFrame which has a column with times in the format hhmm and am looking to filter out rows where the time is more than a particular time e.g. 08:00.

I know that if I only had convert 1 value I could do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22221858/compare-string-in-format-hhmm-to-time-now-in-python) but I'm working on a whole column of data here.  I'm also trying to avoid creating a new column just for the sake of this comparison because I'm filtering on a number of other things as well (though I will do if this is the only way).

Does anyone know who I would do this?

Comment: What is the data type?  String, datetime, Timestamp, etc.  You can check an individual element by (`type(df.column_name.iat[0])` which will check the type of the first element in the series.

Comment: Hi Alex - it's coming up as "numpy.int64"

Comment: And what do the values look like?  `df.columnj_name.iloc[:3]` will return the first three.  Please post as an edit to your question.

Comment: 0)    1213
1)    1213
2)    1213

Comment: could you post you data?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like the following.

```
import pandas as pd
data = ['08:00', '09:00','10:00']
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data) 
dataframe.columns = ['ttime'] 
dataframe[dataframe['ttime'] > '08:00'] #to select where time is greater than 08:00
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Rohit - I've tried this and it comes up with "TypeError: invalid type comparison"

Comment: Strange ! Works fine for me. What is your Pandas version ? Mine is 0.16.2

Comment: So it looks like the column type is numpy.int64 so this must be why it doesn't work